# Code::Blocks process terminated with status 1

Tags: c++, codeblocks

My default "Hello world" code from code::blocks terminated with status 1.
I can't open it! Does anyone know why?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This is what it shows when I compile:

```
mingw32-g++.exe  -o bin\Debug\Bucky.exe obj\Debug\main.o   
mingw32-g++.exe: Internal error: Aborted (program collect2)
Please submit a full bug report.
See <URL:http://www.mingw.org/bugs.shtml> for instructions.
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
0 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
```

Thanks!

- Jesper

Comment: what does it show when you compile ?

Comment: does it show Hello world in output console ???

Comment: did you save the file in .cpp format ?

Comment: I would try to clean the debug folder and restart the compile. Either your compiler is horribly broken, there is some file corruption or possibly you do not have permissions to write files in the destination.

Comment: @KhairulBasar I don't even get to see the output console.
Also I'm using  build & run.
@ drescherjm okay, it's in a folder on my desktop, and I am an admin so it shouldn't be a problem!

Comment: btw, I'm a beginner at c++ and the programs you're using to code with it!

Comment: Have you build it at least one time? Maybe check if your .exe is running either on a window or a process.

Comment: Okay, so I fixed it. I installed all the mingw stuff.. Told ya, I am a noob at this stuff XD

Comment: Install MingGW 64 and configure compiler properly, your 32 bit MinGW is not working.

Answer (score 2):

Check in code::blocks application 
Settings > environment 
Once in the environment settings make sure that the drop down box at the bottom on the window has the correct console selected
In my instance it was set to xterm  -T $TITLE -e 
I am running code::blocks on Linux mint Sarah, my distribution did not come with xterm terminal but rather xfce terminal 
Once I changed to correct console the problem was resolved

-D

Comment: Seems like OP is on Windows.